# Riesz representation theorem in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open set and let $C_{c}\left(\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right)$
be the space of continuous, compactly supported functions on $\Omega.$

We now consider two different topologies on $C_{c}\left(\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right):$
$$
T_{1}:=\left[C_{c}\left(\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right);\left|\cdot\right|_{L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)}\right]\quad and\quad T_{2}:=\left[C_{c}\left(\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right);\textrm{the inductive topology}\right].
$$
We have $T_{1}$ a normed space but $T_{2}$ just a topological vector
space in general. We now consider "continuous" (w.r.t these topologies) linear
functionals on $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}:$ 
$$
F_{1}:T_{1}\rightarrow\mathbb{\mathbb{R}}\quad and\quad F_{2}:T_{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.
$$
(By definition, the statement of continuity is equivalent to: there
exists $C>0$ such that $\left|\left\langle F_{1},f\right\rangle \right|\leq C\left|f\right|_{L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)}$;
$\forall f\in C_{c}\left(\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right)$; and
for any compact subset $K\subseteq\Omega,$ there exists $C_{K}>0$
such that $\left|\left\langle F_{2},f\right\rangle \right|\leq C_{K}\left|f\right|_{L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)};$
$\forall f\in C_{c}\left(\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right),suppf\subseteq K.$)

From Exercise 16, [https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/245b-notes-12-continuous-functions-on-locally-compact-hausdorff-spaces/#rrt] there exists a unique, **finite** (signed) Radon measure
$\mu$ on $\Omega$ such that 
$$
\left\langle F_{1},f\right\rangle =\intop_{\Omega}fd\mu;\forall f\in C_{c}\left(\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right).
$$

**My question is**: is it true that 
$$
\left\langle F_{2},f\right\rangle =\intop_{\Omega}fd\eta;\forall f\in C_{c}\left(\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right);
$$
for some (unique, but may not be finite) signed Radon measure $\eta$
on $\Omega?$

**Attempt**: I think it's true. First, in the case of "positive linear
functional", we already know it is the case [Theorem 8, https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/245b-notes-12-continuous-functions-on-locally-compact-hausdorff-spaces/#rrt]. Therefore, we firstly
prove that: any continuous linear functional $F_{2}$ can be represented
as $F_{2}=H-G,$ with $H:T_{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $G:T_{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ positive linear functionals. But what is the point of using the inductive topology in this stage?

Comment: With inductive topology do you mean the topology where the pointwise evaluations are to be continuous? From some of what you have written it seems you mean the topology given by
$$\lim_{K\subset\Omega} (C(K),\|\cdot\|_{K,\infty})$$
where $K$ are compact subsets, which I believe is the same as $C_c(\Omega)$.

Comment: For the definition of the inductive limit topology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics), it's like the def. of the topology of test functions in the distribution theory, but here we consider $C_{c}\left(\Omega\right)$ instead of $C_{c}^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$.

Comment: What is your definition of $C_{c}(\Omega)$?

Comment: $C_c(\Omega)$ is the space of compactly supported continuous functions on $\Omega$ together with sup norm $\|\phi\|=\sup_{x\in\Omega}|\phi(x)|$.

Comment: Right now I cannot remember my argument that the two topologies are the same, and am unsure if it is true. However $T_2$ is finer than $T_1$, so any functional that is continuous on $T_2$ must be continuous on $T_1$.

Comment: The inductive topology is a very strong topology, that is, it contains lots of open sets. I don't think $T_{1} \equiv T_{2}$.

Comment: Are you sure that any continuous functional on $T_{2}$ is also continuous on $T_{1}$? Look at the definition, it's quite weird to say this at least!

Comment: Blah, stupid of me. Maps into $T_2$ are $T_1$ continuous not maps from $T_2$... sorry. I'll trim the comments to remove some spam.

Answer (score 2):

You can localize Riesz Theorem on the first space to obtain it in the second one. 
Choose some continuous functions $\phi_i \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $\phi_i=1$ on $B_i(0)$ (the ball with radius $i$) and $\phi_i=0$ outside $B_{i+1}(0)$. Then define for $f\in T_2$
$$
F_2^i(f) := F_2(f \cdot \phi_i).
$$
Notice that when $f\in T_2$ also $f\cdot \phi_i\in T_2$. Notice also that $f\cdot \phi_i \to f$ in $T_2$. So, $F_2^i(f) \to F_2(f)$ for each $f\in T_2$.

Moreover each $F_2^i$ is also continuous on $T_1$ hence there exists a finite Radon measure $\mu^i$ such that $F^i_2(f) = \int f \, d\mu^i$.

Now we have
$$
F_2(f) = \lim_i F_2^i(f) = \lim_i \int f \, d \mu^i = \int f \, d \mu
$$
where in the last equation we have introduced the set function $\mu(E) := \lim_i \mu_i(E)$. This set function coincides with $\mu_i$ in $B_i(0)$ hence is actually a measure itself (*** this point should be clarified, but somewhat depends on how non finite signed 
measures have been defined ***)